# How to find range overlap in python?

Tags: python, range

What is the best way in Python to determine what values in two ranges overlap?

For example:

```
x = range(1,10)
y = range(8,20)

(The answer I am looking for would be the integers 8 and 9.)
```

Given a range, x, what is the best way to iterate through another range, y and output all values that are shared by both ranges?

**EDIT:**

As a follow-up, I realized that I also need to know if x does or does not overlap y. I am looking for a way to iterate through a list of ranges and and do a number of additional things with range that overlap. Is there a simple True/False statement to accomplish this?

Comment: Specify the characteristics of the range (step always equal +1? or can it be -2?)

Comment: My ranges are all in +1 steps.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try with set intersection:

```
x = range(1,10)
y = range(8,20)
xs = set(x)
xs.intersection(y)
```

Output:

```
set([8, 9])
```

Note that `intersection` accepts any iterable as an argument (`y` is not required to be converted to a *set* for the operation).
There is an operator equivalent to the `intersection` method: `&` but, in this case, it [requires both arguments to be sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).

Comment: I find that intersection with operator `&` is much more intuitive.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the help. I think the intersection method will work perfectly. Also, is there a way to just ask Python if any values or x are in y? A simple True/False statement?

Comment: @dr.bunsen look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821329/instersection-or-object-for-object-in-set-if-object-in-other-set . You can also do `bool(x.intersection(y))`  (being x, y sets)

Comment: @joaquin Thank you very much for the help. I'm going to read the references you suggested and see if I can solve my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @dr.bunsen This answer doesn't deserve all these upvotes, nor to be accepted. 1) This "solution" is 2.5 slower than the Andrew's solution (see comparison in my answer) 2) the result isn't sorted, since it is a set; that may be a drawback in some cases

Comment: @eyquem maybe the OP feels more comfortable with the simplicity (you want intersection? then you do `intersection`), readability (no need for comments here) and the generality of this approach (it does not assume step 1 or same step for both ranges and you can use it for other iterables, not only for ranges). Speed is not always the more important factor (although the `itersection` approach is faster than the plaes `&` and much more faster than list comprehension (python 2.6), both still very interesting approaches,imho. Anyway, we are talking of several microseconds to execute the code here).

Comment: @joaquin - If he feels more confortable with **intersection**, OK - I admit that **intersection** is more readable - I admit that your solution is more general; but is it necessary to do more than required ? You want step=1, you do step=1 ! - Speed: it depends; I imagine that the real case may have to do with long ranges and speed may be an important criterium. -- Personnaly, I presume that, the starting objects being ranges, we might think that it's quasi certain that it's required that the result is also ordered as a range. You didn't mention this point.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and discussion. I ultimately choose this answer because of readability and the added benefit of duplicate removal with `set()`.

Comment: You would not want to do that to find intersection between `range(0, 21984762198598125721534)` and `range(21984762198598125721123, 45823914893546328945328456)`. There is an O(1) solution in answer by Andrew Clark, which would be the way to go.

Answer (score 149):

If the step is always +1 (which is the default for range) the following should be more efficient than converting each list to a set or iterating over either list:

```
range(max(x[0], y[0]), min(x[-1], y[-1])+1)
```

Comment: Really, this should be the accepted answer. It is a one line, O(1) intersection, whereas the others are O(n) at best, O(n^2) at worst.

Comment: Some tests I ran indicate it may be marginally faster to check x[0] <= y[0] <= x[-1] etc etc, sequentially. But hardly significant. This is more elegant.

Comment: This solution doesn't give us the correct output when there is no overlap between the two ranges.

Comment: Sure it does, if there is no overlap the result is an empty range as expected.

Comment: Why not `range(max(x.start, y.start), min(x.stop, y.stop))`? As a caveat, this solution only works if `x.step == 1 and y.step == 1`.

Comment: As @Pedram mentioned, this solution will also output a range even if there is no overlap, the range will have start and stop, but the range will in fact be empty. You can check if the range is empty  by using `len(range)` -> will be 0 if there is no overlap

Comment: What about decimals in the input numbers ??  Range doesn't allow for them.

Comment: Am I going crazy or does this not work as expected? Trying it with `[11,20]` and `[1,10]` should produce no overlap, yet this spits out `range(11,10)`. EDIT: I suppose that's an invalid range, but the output is rather misleading.

Comment: @turnip That's a correct output. Note that range(11, 10) makes no sense for (default) step 1. You can verify that len(range(11, 10)) == 0. Also, if you do bool(range(11, 10)) you get False

Answer (score 19):

The answers above seem mostly overly complex. This one liner works perfectly in Python3, takes ranges as inputs and output. It also handles illegal ranges. To get the values just iterate over the result if not None.

```
# return overlap range for two range objects or None if no ovelap
# does not handle step!=1
def range_intersect(r1, r2):
    return range(max(r1.start,r2.start), min(r1.stop,r2.stop)) or None
```

Comment: Using start/stop seems much easier than remembering to add 1 to the range end when using [0]/[-1] list indices.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [set](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)s for that, but be aware that `set(list)` removes all duplicate entries from the `list`:

```
>>> x = range(1,10)
>>> y = range(8,20)
>>> list(set(x) & set(y))
[8, 9]
```

Comment: Well, `range`s don't contain duplicates anyway. Also, using `xrange` is possible saves some (potentially much, depending on range sizes) memory during construction.

Answer (score 13):

If you looking for the overlap between two real-valued bounded intervals, then this is quite nice:

```
def overlap(start1, end1, start2, end2):
    """how much does the range (start1, end1) overlap with (start2, end2)"""
    return max(max((end2-start1), 0) - max((end2-end1), 0) - max((start2-start1), 0), 0)
```

I couldn't find this online anywhere so I came up with this and I'm posting here.

Comment: Anyone have a reference explaining this, or a more readable version?

Answer (score 11):

One option is to just use list comprehension like:

```
x = range(1,10) 
y = range(8,20) 

z = [i for i in x if i in y]
print z
```

Comment: As far as I can see xrange.__contains__ from Python 2.x doesn't have this optimization. This is sloow under python 2.7:  rng = xrange(20, 1000000000); 10 in rng

Comment: '10 in rng' (False) is slow and '100 in rng' (True) is fast under Python 2.7; both are fast under Python 3.2.

Answer (score 8):

This is the answer for the simple range with step=1 case (99% of the time), which can be **2500x faster** as shown in the benchmark when comparing long ranges using sets (when you are just interested in knowing if there is overlap):

```
x = range(1,10) 
y = range(8,20)

def range_overlapping(x, y):
    if x.start == x.stop or y.start == y.stop:
        return False
    return x.start <= y.stop and y.start <= x.stop

>>> range_overlapping(x, y)
True
```

To find the overlapping values:

```
def overlap(x, y):
    if not range_overlapping(x, y):
        return set()
    return set(range(max(x.start, y.start), min(x.stop, y.stop)+1))
```

Visual help:

```
|  |           |    |
  |  |       |    |
```

Benchmark:

```
x = range(1,10)
y = range(8,20)

In [151]: %timeit set(x).intersection(y)
2.74 µs ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [152]: %timeit range_overlapping(x, y)
1.4 µs ± 2.91 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**Conclusion**: even for small ranges, it is twice as fast.

```
x = range(1,10000)
y = range(50000, 500000)

In [155]: %timeit set(x).intersection(y)
43.1 ms ± 158 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [156]: %timeit range_overlapping(x, y)
1.75 µs ± 88.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**Conclusion**: you want to use the range_overlapping function in this case as it is **2500x faster** (my personal record in speedup)

Comment: I think in `range_overlapping`, it might be sufficient to check `x.start <= y.stop and y.start <= x.stop`. As a matter of fact, I think the two expressions you use (separated by `or`) are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

For "if x does or does not overlap y" :

```
for a,b,c,d in ((1,10,10,14),
                (1,10,9,14),
                (1,10,4,14),
                (1,10,4,10),
                (1,10,4,9),
                (1,10,4,7),
                (1,10,1,7),
                (1,10,-3,7),
                (1,10,-3,2),
                (1,10,-3,1),
                (1,10,-11,-5)):
    x = range(a,b)
    y = range(c,d)
    print 'x==',x
    print 'y==',y
    b = not ((x[-1]<y[0]) or (y[-1]<x[0]))
    print '    x %s y' % ("does not overlap","   OVERLAPS  ")[b]
    print
```

result

```
x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [10, 11, 12, 13]
    x does not overlap y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    x    OVERLAPS   y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    x    OVERLAPS   y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    x    OVERLAPS   y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    x    OVERLAPS   y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [4, 5, 6]
    x    OVERLAPS   y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    x    OVERLAPS   y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    x    OVERLAPS   y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1]
    x    OVERLAPS   y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [-3, -2, -1, 0]
    x does not overlap y

x== [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y== [-11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6]
    x does not overlap y
```

### Edit 1

Speeds comparison:

```
from time import clock

x = range(-12,15)
y = range(-5,3)
te = clock()
for i in xrange(100000):
    w = set(x).intersection(y)
print '                     set(x).intersection(y)',clock()-te


te = clock()
for i in xrange(100000):
    w = range(max(x[0], y[0]), min(x[-1], y[-1])+1)
print 'range(max(x[0], y[0]), min(x[-1], y[-1])+1)',clock()-te
```

result

```
                     set(x).intersection(y) 0.951059981087
range(max(x[0], y[0]), min(x[-1], y[-1])+1) 0.377761978129
```

The ratio of these execution's times is 2.5

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the overlap of ranges with arbitrary steps you can use my package https://github.com/avnr/rangeplus which provides 
a Range() class compatible with Python range(), plus some goodies including intersections:

```
>>> from rangeplus import Range
>>> Range(1, 100, 3) & Range(2, 100, 4)
Range(10, 100, 12)
>>> Range(200, -200, -7) & range(5, 80, 2)  # can intersect with Python range() too
Range(67, 4, -14)
```

Range() can also be unbound (when stop is None the Range goes on to +/-infinity):

```
>>> Range(1, None, 3) & Range(3, None, 4)
Range(7, None, 12)
>>> Range(253, None, -3) & Range(208, 310, 5)
Range(253, 207, -15)
```

The intersection is computed, not iterated, which makes the efficiency of the implementation independent of the length of the Range().

Answer (score 2):

This solution generates integers that are in the intersection of an arbitrary number of `range` objects in **`O(1)`** memory.

*Disclosure:* I got this from a user in [Python Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52187555#52187555) after I tried something else... less elegant.

#### Solution

```
def range_intersection(*ranges):
    ranges = set(ranges)  # `range` is hashable so we can easily eliminate duplicates
    if not ranges: return
    
    shortest_range = min(ranges, key=len)  # we will iterate over one, so choose the shortest one
    ranges.remove(shortest_range)          # note: `range` has a length, so we can use `len`
    
    for i in shortest_range:
        if all(i in range_ for range_ in ranges): yield i  # Finally, `range` implements `__contains__`
                                                           # by checking if an iteger satisfies it's simple formula
```

#### Testing

OP's problem

```
x = range(1,10)
y = range(8,20)
list(range_intersection(x, y))

[8, 9]
```

My example

```
limit = 10_000
list(range_intersection(
    range(2, limit, 2),
    range(3, limit, 3),
    range(5, limit, 5),
    range(41, limit, 41),
))

[1230, 2460, 3690, 4920, 6150, 7380, 8610, 9840]
```

Comment: stumbled upon this answer today. Nicely done :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working exclusively with ranges, with a step of `1`, you can do it quickly with math.

```
def range_intersect(range_x,range_y):
    if len(range_x) == 0 or len(range_y) == 0:
        return []
    # find the endpoints
    x = (range_x[0], range_x[-1]) # from the first element to the last, inclusive
    y = (range_y[0], range_y[-1])
    # ensure min is before max
    # this can be excluded if the ranges must always be increasing
    x = tuple(sorted(x))
    y = tuple(sorted(y))
    # the range of the intersection is guaranteed to be from the maximum of the min values to the minimum of the max values, inclusive
    z = (max(x[0],y[0]),min(x[1],y[1]))
    if z[0] < z[1]:
        return range(z[0], z[1] + 1) # to make this an inclusive range
    else:
        return [] # no intersection
```

On a pair of ranges each with over 10^7 elements, this took under a second, independent of how many elements overlapped. I tried with 10^8 or so elements, but my computer froze for a while. I doubt you'd be working with lists that long.