# How to get overlap range of two range

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have the following ranges in interval [1-15]

I want to find the overlap ranges between people 1 & 2.

Person1 [1, 3] [5, 10]
Person2 [2, 4] [8, 15]

Here I should get a list of Ranges which are [2,3], [8, 10].

What I've found so far is to loop by person1's range, then by person2's ranges, then for each element of each range, then using conditional test. 
This solution doesn't satisfy me as it's O(n). More there're range of elements, more my algo will going to loop for each element of each range and that will take time if I want to see the insection between theses ranges

Person1: [100000; 150000] and [90000; 140000].
Person2: [105000; 110000] and [130000; 140050]

Note that a range is represented in my code by:

```
public class Range{
    public int Start {get;set;}
    public int End {get;set;}
}
```

So what's the most efficient way to find the overlap ranges?

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: there's similar question here [How to find range overlap in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821156/how-to-find-range-overlap-in-python) but I don't understand python code.

Comment: How could you know if more overlap exists or not without checking each of the n ranges?

Comment: I think he means n being the range of elements, not the number of ranges. For example what is the overlap of [1,1000] vs. [100,2000] without iterating 2000 times and testing each element. He wants to compute the intersecting range iterating only the ranges (in this case two of them) instead of the elements (2000 of them).

Comment: Hatchet is right, I'm gonna edit my post so its clearer

Comment: [Merge Overlapping Intervals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/) algorithm can give some leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the merge step of the mergesort algorithm. If the ranges for each person are sorted this method can be adapted to compute the overlaps very easily.

```
Loop
   Get the range that starts next (R1)
   if the next range of the other person (R2) starts before R1 ends
      Add the range from begin of R2 and min( end of R1 end of R2 ) to results
   Increase the counter for the person which gave you R1
```

If your ranges are known to be non adjacent (i.e. if there is always at least one number between to consecutive ranges). The solution will also be. Else you might need an extra compaction step to ensure that adjacent ranges will be put into one range.

The nice thing is that this works for any ordered type and not just ints, and you can intersect any number of ranges very fast ( O(n+m) ).

Answer (score 3):

Sort the starts and ends of the ranges.. keeping information alongside as to whether its a range-start or finish... for your example you'll get this:

```
1 start
2 start
3 end
4 end
5 start
8 start
10 end
15 end
```

Now loop over these points and keep a counter.. +1 for a start -1 for an end. This counter is the number of overlapping segments at any time. If you want the boundaries you need to test each time you increase or decrease the counter. If you increase it from 1 to 2 this is a start of an overlapping range.. the end of the overlapping range will be when you decrease the counter from 2 to 1

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification. What about something like this...

```
public static IList<Range> GetListIntersections(IList<Range> rangeList1, IList<Range> rangeList2)
{
    var intersection = new List<Range>();

    //add intersection of each range
    foreach (var x in rangeList1)
    {
        foreach (var y in rangeList2)
        {
            var intersect = GetIntersection(x, y);
            if (intersect != null)
            {
                intersection.Add(intersect);
            }
        }
    }

    //remove ranges that are subsets of other ranges
    intersection.RemoveAll(x => intersection.Any(y => y != x && y.Start >= x.Start && y.End <= x.End));

    return intersection;
}

public static Range GetIntersection(Range range1, Range range2)
{
    int greatestStart = range1.Start > range2.Start ? range1.Start : range2.Start;
    int smallestEnd = range1.End < range2.End ? range1.End : range2.End;

    //no intersection
    if (greatestStart > smallestEnd)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return new Range { Start = greatestStart, End = smallestEnd };
}
```

Comment: I have a IList of ranges. I need to retrieve

Comment: It's simple and it works but it's O(N^2) so limited to small sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you're looping by 'person1's range, then by person2's ranges' - I'm not sure what that means without seeing the code.

I can't see how you would get better than O(n), but you can iterate through the range only once. A better data structure might be a `bool[]` or `BitArray`.

```
var person1 = new bool[15] { /* set values */ };
var person2 = new bool[15] { /* set values */ };

var overlap = new bool[15];

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    overlap[i] = person1[i] && person2[i];
}
```

Comment: If the ranges are sorted, he can walk the ranges of the two persons, compare the range he's currently looking at of person1 to person2, staying at the range with the higher end value, moving to the next range of the person with the lower end value. This would compute the intersection in 4 steps instead of 15.

Comment: @hatchet that's true but big Oh is an upper limit - or 'worst case'. If the 'ranges' where like [1][3][5] etc then there'd be more steps than this method. Both are O(n). Note I'm just suggesting what I consider to be a clearer method of describing his data - & looping through a BitArray is insanely fast.

Comment: I agree that the worst cases would have similar cost, the worst case being [1,1][2,2][3,3]..., but your best and average cases will be the same as the worst case. Walking the ranges would likely be much more efficient for typical cases.

Comment: @hatchet you may be right but I don't assume to know the typical case. Walking the ranges requires two iterators (you need to walk both simultaneously) and more complex logic. The best case of this algorithm will have the same `computational complexity` as worst case of walking both ranges, but will be faster and simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. What I meant by person1's range and person2's range is.... Better I write the idea here : http://pastebin.com/PJ905id1 BTW, I don't understand your solution consisted in array of bool... can you provide more details ?