# How do I write a method that finds all the intersections in an array of ranges?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, set, intersection, intervals

I have array similar to this

```
[
 [0, 10]**,
 [1, 3]**,
 [5, 11]**,
 [14, 20]**,
 [10, 11]**
]
```

** Denotes an object containing the start and end indexes shown in the array

Now, the intersections are `[1, 3], [5,10], [10,11]`

What is the best way to write a method that returns the objects containing of the intersecting sets?
(Could just store them in an array of conflicted stuff as we go along)

The biggest issue I'm having is how do I do this such that each object is compared with eachother object?

there are n! ways to do this (i think, I'm a bit rusty on my combinatorics)

Comment: start and end indices of text blocks from large-ish pieces of text.

Comment: Could you explain how you get from the starting data to the intersections and the conflicting sets?  That's not clear at all.

Comment: What have you tried? I take it you want the intersecting pairs to be `(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (2, 4)`.

Comment: @MattFenwick, how I get the data isn't important, I don't think.

Comment: @JimMischel I'm stuck on the comparing each object to every other object part. I'm thinking I might need to do something recursive. =\

Comment: Nor do I, just trying to understand the problem.

Comment: You might look into interval trees: http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~jstewart/378notes/22intervals/. You can construct it in `O(n log n)`, and you can query `n` items in `n log n`. You might  be able to walk it in `O(n)`, though.

Comment: To compare every object with every other is a simple nested loop. Look into selection sort. That will work well if your number of ranges is relatively small.

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438404/how-to-get-overlap-range-of-two-range (especially the second answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the intervals by start time (or instead sort an array of indices by start time so you don't lose the indices).

After this you can do a single pass detecting all intersections/conflicts.

```
Range array[N];

sort(array);
int i=0;
while(i<N){
    Range curr = array[i];  //invariant: curr doesn't intersect with anyone befor it
    i++;
    while(i < N && array[i].start <= curr.end){
        output that curr and array[i] intersect;
        if(array[i].end > curr.end){
            curr = array[i]
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, this is the "selection sort" method, right? Compare each range with all ranges below it, with an early out testing start time against curr_end.

Comment: I don't quite understand this, could you explain a bit better? you are using a stack. =\ Oh, and I should say the indexes are as important, as this is actually an array of objects that have a start and end index. I'll update my question, as it is relevant.

Comment: ehm.. not quite. you have too keep the biggest `.end`, otherwise you can miss intersections.

Comment: is this the most efficent way to do this? i mean, it looks like O(n^n)

Comment: It looks O(n) to me. You start with i=0 and i goes up to N one by one. (note how each array element is processed only once)