# How to print out only records with intervals, from one file, not overlapping with those from another file

Tags: python

I have two files representing records with intervals.

file1.txt

```
a 5 10
a 13 19
a 27 39
b 4 9
b 15 19
c 20 33
c 39 45
```

and

file2.txt

```
something id1 a 4 9 commentx
something id2 a 14 18 commenty
something id3 a 1 4 commentz
something id5 b 3 9 commentbla
something id6 b 16 18 commentbla
something id7 b 25 29 commentblabla
something id8 c 5 59 hihi
something id9 c 40 45 hoho
something id10 c 32 43 haha
```

What I would like to do is to make a file representing only records of the file2 for which, if the column 3 of the file2 is identical to the column 1 of the file1, the range (column 4 and 5) is not overlapping with that of the file1 (column 2 and 3).

The expected output file should be in a file

test.result

```
something id3 a 1 4 commentz
something id7 b 25 29 commentblabla
```

I have tried to use the following python code:

```
import csv
with open ('file2') as protein, open('file1') as position, open ('test.result',"r+") as fallout:
    writer = csv.writer(fallout, delimiter=' ')
    for rowinprot in csv.reader(protein, delimiter=' '):
        for rowinpos in csv.reader(position, delimiter=' '):
            if rowinprot[2]==rowinpos[0]:
                if rowinprot[4]<rowinpos[1] or rowinprot[3]>rowinpos[2]:
                    writer.writerow(rowinprot)
```

This did not seem to work...I had the following result:

```
something id1 a 4 9 commentx
something id1 a 4 9 commentx
something id1 a 4 9 commentx
```

which apparently is not what I want.

What did I do wrong? It seems to be in the conditional loops. Still, I couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do looping in a loop is not a good way. Try to avoid to do such things.
I think you could cache the content of file1 first use a dict object. Then, when looping file2 you can use the dict object to find your need things.So, i will code like bellow:

```
with open("file1.csv", "r") as protein, open("file2.csv", "r") as postion, open("result.csv", "w") as fallout:
    writer = csv.writer(fallout, delimiter=' ')
    protein_dict = {}
    for rowinprt in csv.reader(protein, delimiter=' '):
        key = rowinprt[0]
        sub_value = (int(rowinprt[1]), int(rowinprt[2]))
        protein_dict.setdefault(key, [])
        protein_dict[key].append(sub_value)

    for pos in csv.reader(postion, delimiter=' '):
        id_key = pos[2]
        id_min = int(pos[3])
        id_max = int(pos[4])
        if protein_dict.has_key(id_key) and all([ id_max < _min or _max < id_min for _min, _max in protein_dict[id_key]]):
            writer.writerow(pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill, but you could create a class to represent intervals and use it to make fairly readable code:

```
import csv

class Interval(object):
    """ Representation of a closed interval.
        a & b can be numeric, a datetime.date, or any other comparable type.
    """
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.lowerbound, self.upperbound = (a, b) if a < b else (b, a)
    def __contains__(self, val):
        return self.lowerbound <= val <= self.upperbound
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({}, {})'.format(self.__class__.__name__,
                                   self.lowerbound, self.upperbound)

filename1 = 'afile1.txt'
filename2 = 'afile2.txt'
filename3 = 'test.result'

intervals = {}  # master dictionary of intervals
with open(filename1, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        cls, a, b = row[0], int(row[1]), int(row[2])
        intervals.setdefault(cls, []).append(Interval(a, b))

with open(filename2, 'rb') as f1, open(filename3, 'wb') as f2:
    reader = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=' ')
    writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        cls, a, b = row[2], int(row[3]), int(row[4])
        if cls in intervals:
            for interval in intervals[cls]:
                # check for overlap
                if ((a in interval) or (b in interval) or
                    (a < interval.lowerbound and b > interval.upperbound)):
                    break  # skip
            else:
                writer.writerow(row)  # no overlaps
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, you will have to change three things:

1. Your loop over the position reader is only run once, because the reader runs through the file, the first time the loop is run. Afterwards, he searches for the next item at the end of the file. You'll have to rewind the file each time, before the loop is run. See e.g. ([Python csv.reader: How do I return to the top of the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431752/python-csv-reader-how-do-i-return-to-the-top-of-the-file))
2. The csv reader returns string objects. If you compare them via smaller/larger signs, it compares them as if they were words. So it checks first digit vs first digit, and so on. To get the comparison right, you'll have to cast to integer first.
3. Lastly, your program now would return a line out of the protein file every time it does not overlap with a line in the position file that has the same identifier. So for example the first protein line would be printed twice for the second and third position line. As I understand, this is not what you want, so you'll have to check ALL position lines to be valid, before printing.

Generally, the code is probably not the most elegant way to do it but to get correct results with something close to what you wrote, you might want to try something along the lines of:

```
with open ('file2.txt') as protein, open('file1.txt') as position, open ('test.result',"r+") as fallout:
    writer = csv.writer(fallout, delimiter=' ')
    for rowinprot in csv.reader(protein, delimiter=' '):
        position.seek(0)
        valid = True
        for rowinpos in csv.reader(position, delimiter=' '):
            if rowinprot[2]==rowinpos[0]:
                 if not (int(rowinprot[4])<int(rowinpos[1]) or int(rowinprot[3])>int(rowinpos[2])):
                     valid = False
        if valid:
            writer.writerow(rowinprot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm working for you:

```
def is_overlapping(x, y):
    return len(range(max(x[0], y[0]), min(x[-1], y[-1])+1)) > 0

position_file = r"file1.txt"
positions = [line.strip().split() for line in open(position_file).read().split('\n')]

protein_file = r"file2.txt"
proteins = [(line.strip().split()[2:5], line) for line in open(protein_file).read().split('\n')]

fallout_file = r"result.txt"
with open(fallout_file, 'w') as fallout:
    for index, protein_info in enumerate(proteins):
        try:
            test_position = positions[index]
        except IndexError:
            # If files do not have the same size the loop will end
            break
        protein_position, protein_line = protein_info

        # If identifier is different, write line and check next line
        if protein_position[0] != test_position[0]:
            print(protein_line)
            fallout.write(protein_line)
            continue

        # Here identifiers are identical, then we check if they overlap
        test_range = range(int(test_position[1]), int(test_position[2]))
        protein_range = range(int(protein_position[1]), int(protein_position[2]))
        if not is_overlapping(protein_range, test_range):
            print(protein_line)
            fallout.write(protein_line + '\n')
```

Concerning the overlapping test, a good snippet was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6821298/2531279