# Timestamp filtering with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with those two dataframes. df1 is a list of potential shift that the person can do. And df2 is a basically his/her schedule when he/she is available.

Starts_at is the begining of the shift/availability ; Ends_at is the end of the shift/availability

I would like to to remove all the potential shift that the person cannot do because of the schedule. Like for example you can see that this person is not available on the morning so I should remove 0 and 3 index in n1

I started doing something like that `df1[df1.starts_at[0] >= df2.starts_at]` but it is not working

```
n1 = {'starts_at': {0: Timestamp('2019-06-02 09:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-06-02 17:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2019-06-02 14:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2019-06-03 09:30:00')},
 'ends_at': {0: Timestamp('2019-06-02 17:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-06-02 22:30:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2019-06-02 22:30:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2019-06-03 13:00:00')}}

n2 = {'starts_at': {0: Timestamp('2019-06-01 14:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-06-01 14:41:32.464000'),
  2: Timestamp('2019-06-01 15:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2019-06-02 10:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2019-06-02 14:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2019-06-02 17:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2019-06-02 17:30:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2019-06-03 17:00:00')},
 'ends_at': {0: Timestamp('2019-06-01 22:30:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-06-01 22:32:44.862000'),
  2: Timestamp('2019-06-01 22:30:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2019-06-02 18:30:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2019-06-03 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2019-06-03 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2019-06-02 21:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2019-06-03 23:00:00')}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(n1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(n2)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: PD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462218/find-date-range-overlap-in-python

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.greater_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.greater_equal.html#numpy.greater_equal) and [`np.less_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html#numpy.less_equal) with as ufunc with [outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) to be able to compare all 'starts_at' between both dfs at once and the same for 'ends_at'. Then use `any` over the column to be able to catch the rows in df1 that have any possibility:

```
mask = ( np.less_equal.outer(df1.starts_at, df2.starts_at)
         & np.greater_equal.outer(df1.ends_at, df2.ends_at)).any(1)
print (df1[mask])
            starts_at             ends_at
1 2019-06-02 17:00:00 2019-06-02 22:30:00
2 2019-06-02 14:00:00 2019-06-02 22:30:00
```

For a bit more details, `np.less_equal.outer(df1.starts_at, df2.starts_at)` gives an array where rows are the value of `df1.starts_at` and they are compared to the values of starts_at in `df2` and what we look for is if the starts in `df1` are less (or earlier) than the one in `df2`:

```
array([[False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) power:

```
i,j=np.where((df1.starts_at.values[:,None]>=df2.starts_at.values)&\
            (df1.ends_at.values[:,None]<=df2.ends_at.values))

#select values and remove duplicates
dfsel=df1.iloc[i][~df1.iloc[i].index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```