# Pandas dataframe - comparing values in other columns only for rows with matching labels in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im a little confused about how to incorporate if, then statements into dataframes.
DF:

| name | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2018-08-24 | 2019-09-24 |
| A | 2018-08-25 | 2018-08-24 |
| A | 2017-08-25 | 2018-08-24 |
| A | 2016-08-25 | 2018-08-24 |
| B | 2018-08-25 | 2019-09-24 |
| C | 2018-08-25 | 2019-09-24 |
| C | 2015-04-25 | 2019-09-24 |
| C | 2018-06-25 | 2019-09-24 |
| C | 2008-06-25 | 2019-09-24 |
| D | 2018-06-25 | 2019-09-24 |
| D | 2008-06-25 | 2019-09-24 |

I want to first compare the values in column, 'name'. If these values are the same, I want to proceed with a calculation for the other two columns.
For example, the first two rows have the same string in 'name', so I want to proceed evaluating if date2-date1 overlaps between the first row and second row.
What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Are there multiple rows with duplicate names? i.e. Are there at most only two rows with name `A` or is it possible for three or more rows to have name `A`?

Comment: you mean 2 adjacent rows at a time? or all combinations of rows? or all "groups" of names?

Comment: It sounds like you probably want to use a groupby on the `name` column, but some more details would be helpful so that people on StackOverflow can more accurately answer your question. Can you give a more extensive example with the expected output DataFrame?

Comment: Yes there can be more than 2 rows with duplicate names. I have edited the example accordingly.

Comment: I think this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462218/find-date-range-overlap-in-python

Comment: What's your expected output?