# Python removing intersection from list 2 out of list 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops, intersection

I've got 2 ranges for which I want to get the overlap. And in a second step remove that overlap from the first range.
Currently the ranges are saved in a list, that has the form of (start value, end value).
So **Range 1** be: 
(5230,7585)

And **Range 2** be: 
(6752,6988)

Is this best possible solution for this, to create variables in which I call the range function like this and compare these like descriped elsewhere
([How to find range overlap in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821156/how-to-find-range-overlap-in-python))

```
x = range(5230,7585)
y = range(6752,6988)
xs = set(x)
xs.intersection(y)
```

Actually I got >30.000 entry in both type of ranges. I am interested in finding the ranges from List 2 (or Ranges 2) that overlap with these of List 1 (Ranges 1). The intersections of List 2 with List 1  shall then be removed from List 1. So that List 1 Look like this

```
List1 = [...,[5230,6752], [6988,7585], ...]
```

I tried to do it with a lot of for loops and if statements but it soon got really confusing and unclear. I can post my code this far, however I am not sure that this would help. 
Is there a library or built-in function that can realize this task better (than manually via for-if-statements). What is the most pythonic way to remove the intersection.

would it be?

```
xintrm = xs.difference(y)
```

Best Regards,

**Edit 1:**
Hey thanks @ the moderator. I am having trouble with transfering the solutions suggested in the other thread to my situation. Since I dont have just one range in which I want to finde the intervals but instead I have multiple ranges to search for intercepts

Comment: Hi Thanks, this question was kinda helpfull. However, the main difference is that the author in the first question, had only 1 range to search in and knew already that all intervalls are inside that range. In my case I have not one range but multiple ranges, where the intervalls can start before the range, in the middle of it, or after it. Does that qualify as a new question?

Comment: I've found a solution :)