# Compare numbers in multiple python lists

Tags: python-3.x

How can I compare the numbers of multiple lists to test if there is no overlap in the number ranges across all lists.

```
a = [1, 8]
b = [9, 13]
c = [14, 20]
```

I want to know if the numbers in the lists overlap with each other.

Comment: To clarify, in your example there would be no overlap with `a`, `b`, and `c`, right?

Comment: If you are working with "ranges" of numbers, you may want to look into `range()`.

Comment: That's correct no overlap with a, b and c. I'm not sure how to compare range (a) to range (b) and range (c).

Comment: See if these help: [How to find range overlap in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6821156/4518341) and [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/464864/4518341) (combining `a`, `b`, and `c`, that is)

Comment: Yep, I was able to get the solution from the How to find range overlap in python? Thanks!!