# Identify blank days from date range excluding overlap

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset which have parent_id, id, start_date and end_date as columns.

I want to check that in a calendar year, how many days a parent_id was not having an id running. The problem is with the “Overlap”. I want to exclude the overlapping days. How can I solve this problem?

Sample Input:

```
parent_id   id  start_date  end_date

ABCD    1   2019-10-26  2020-06-30

ABCD    2   2020-01-02  2020-04-01

ABCD    3   2020-07-09  2020-12-31

ABCD    4   2020-07-14  2020-09-26

EFGH    22  2020-01-02  2020-03-31

EFGH    23  2020-01-02  2020-04-01

EFGH    24  2020-01-15  2020-04-07
```

Sample Output:

```
parent_id   Year (2020)

ABCD    8

EFGH    268
```

So in year 2020 parent_id ABCD was inactive for 8 days. (July 1st to July 8th).

I did refer to similar questions on the portal but none of it worked for my problem.

[Efficient date range overlap calculation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044084/efficient-date-range-overlap-calculation-in-python)

[How to find range overlap in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821156/how-to-find-range-overlap-in-python)

[Find date range overlap in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462218/find-date-range-overlap-in-python)

Comment: Do you need this breakdown per year? Or just total inactive days will do?

Comment: Yes I need a breakdown per year. This is a sample data but my actual file has data from 2011.

Comment: So in your example, do we assume ABCD was inactive from 1 Jan 2019 to 26 Oct 2019?

Comment: Yes. That can be assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you what you need:

```
def count_inactive_days(data):
    all_days = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(data["start_date"].min().year,1,1), pd.Timestamp.today(), freq="D")
    active_days = pd.DatetimeIndex(sorted(set(date for sublist in data.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x["start_date"], x["end_date"], freq="D"), axis=1).to_list() for date in sublist)))
    inactive_days = all_days.to_series().resample("Y").count() - active_days.to_series().resample("Y").count()
    inactive_days.index = inactive_days.index.year
    return inactive_days

>>> pd.concat([df.groupby("parent_id").apply(count_inactive_days)]).unstack()
            2019   2020
parent_id              
ABCD       298.0    8.0
EFGH         NaN  269.0
```

Comment: I did try to implement this. The only catch is for future days. For 2021 some instances show 344 days inactive which should be restricted to current date.

Comment: Gotcha, edited `all_days` to only take days until today into account.

Comment: The code works with a correct logic now. Added a line to avoid negative values when End_Date is in future.

df[df < 0] = 0

Thanks for your help.